# Wordpress pll_ (polylanguage function) usage in jquery

Tags: jquery, wordpress

I am trying to use `pll_` functions (the polylanguage function in wordpress plugin). I would like to change a text after clicking on a button to the corresponding one in every language used. I tried the following code:

```
jQuery('.lm').click(function(){
     jQuery(".motivlevel").html('<?php pll_(CarrierLMSwitch) ?>');
});
```

But unfortunately it does nothing and also stuck some of the previous jQuery methods also. Can anyone help me how to solve this problem?
Any sollution would be good!
Thanks for your help!

Comment: any console error occur

Comment: you can not output on run like javascript ? are you pll_(CarrierLMSwitch) has some kind of value before click functions works ?

Comment: Actualy a have a button whit some text in 3 languages, after click-ing on the button I want to change this text but also in  3 languages, that is I want to use the pll_ function

Comment: you are trying to execute a php function on client and on run time  . Please concentrate on logic now.

Comment: Still what do you suggest how to solve this problem?

Comment: please tell me plugin name and its related task let me find so better solution for you now .

Comment: the plugin is polylang it translates the selected texts to the propper language